# access Lotus notes database using ODBC and C#

Tags: lotus-notes

Please provide some sample code how to access Lotus notes database using ODBC and C#.
Now I am able to accessing database suing NotesSession() class.but I want how to do via ODBC

Thanks and Regards
Naresh Mesineni

---

Thanks for your replay.Still I am facing some problem.I downloaded the NotesSQL 8.5 and installed.
I am trying to get the Notes data using ODBC still It is throwing some error.Here I am attaching connection string.

string sConnString = "Driver={Lotus NotesSQL 8.5 (32-bit) ODBC DRIVER (*.nsf)};" +
                    "Server=serverXXXX;" +
                    "database="DBName;"
                    "Uid=userxxx;" +
                    "Pwd=pwdxxx";

OdbcConnection odbccon = new OdbcConnection(sConnString);
                odbccon.Open();
while opening connection it is throwing error
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
Please provide some solution.it is help full if any one provide sample code with getting data from Notes.

Thanks and Regards
Naresh Mesienni

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the NotesSQL driver, and the [help file is here](http://publib-b.boulder.ibm.com/lotus/c2735080.nsf/a.%20Contents?OpenView).

You can setup a DSN, or use the connection strings [found on connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/lotus-notes)

```
Driver={Lotus NotesSQL 8.51 (32-bit) ODBC DRIVER (*.nsf)};Server=myServerAddress; Database=dbPath\myDb.nsf;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about LEI? (Lotus Enterprise Integrator)

I think is free with Domino and it lets you create ODBC connections and schedules jobs, etc.

You should look into it.

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I know, LEI is not free. Do you have a link about that? It will be useful at my job.

Comment: Back in 2011 at least, I think that you had the right to use LEI as long as you have the license for Lotus Domino. Check with your IBM Sales Rep.